# C# Find if a word is in a document

Tags: c#, regex

I am looking for a way to check if the "foo" word is present in a text file using C#.

I may use a regular expression but I'm not sure that is going to work if the word is splitted in two lines. I got the same issue with a streamreader that enumerates over the lines.

Any comments ?

Comment: First, this sounds like homework; but if it isn't, is the word split with a hyphen when it spans two lines?

Comment: Splitted? Do you mean that the word could be hyphenated? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen#Separating

Comment: By splitted I wanted to say that the word can be uppon two linde : for exemple the letter "f" at the end of a line and then the letters "oo" at the start of the next line. And nop, it isnt homework.

Comment: for that you may need to build a statemachine that only checks the last tow lines or joins the entire file into a single string with no CRLF.  if you want a state machine you can probably base it on what I have below.

Comment: Strip leading and trailing space from all lines.  Join the lines together into one string, getting rid of all line endings.  Now use a regexp or substring match to see if the word is present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here ya go. So we look at the string as we read the file and we keep track of the first word last word combo and check to see if matches your pattern.

```
string pattern = "foo";
string input = null;
string lastword = string.Empty;
string firstword = string.Empty;
bool result = false;

FileStream FS = new FileStream("File name and path", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(FS);

while ((input = SR.ReadLine()) != null) 
{
    firstword = input.Substring(0, input.IndexOf(" "));
    if(lastword.Trim() != string.Empty) { firstword = lastword.Trim() + firstword.Trim(); } 

    Regex RegPattern = new Regex(pattern);
    Match Match1 = RegPattern.Match(input);
    string value1 = Match1.ToString(); 

    if (pattern.Trim() == firstword.Trim() || value1 != string.Empty) { result = true;  }

    lastword = input.Trim().Substring(input.Trim().LastIndexOf(" "));
}
```

Comment: I thought about this as well... but you would have a problem if you have something like "barf oogle" in the file.

Comment: Why would the input file have a brake in the word? where "f" is on one line and "oo" is the beginning of the next?

Comment: Well I really don't think that foo is the word he is really searching for.  My point was that if you do a .Replace(" ", "") it would join all words together.

Comment: Updated the code with some checkup logic to see if the End of previous line + beginning of new line trimmed = pattern. as well as using the regex since thats what was asked for in the solution. I understand the placement of the regex is not optimal but when @toto figures out how he wants to use it he can adjust.

Comment: I changed the first line inside the while condition because this solution wouldn't work for me if the line only had one word. Instead I used this two lines: `int end = (input.IndexOf(" ") == -1) ? input.Length : input.IndexOf(" ");  firstword = input.Substring(0, end);`. Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with a simple search?

If the file is not large, and memory is not a problem, simply read the entire file into a string ([ReadToEnd()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoend.aspx) method), and use string Contains()

Comment: will this handle the case where it is split over consecutive lines?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick quick example using LINQ

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        { //LINQ version
            bool hasFoo = "file.txt".AsLines()
                                    .Any(l => l.Contains("foo"));
        }
        { // No LINQ or Extension Methods needed
            bool hasFoo = false;
            foreach (var line in Tools.AsLines("file.txt"))
                if (line.Contains("foo"))
                {
                    hasFoo = true;
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
}
public static class Tools
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> AsLines(this string filename)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(filename))
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                while (line.EndsWith("-") && !reader.EndOfStream)
                    line = line.Substring(0, line.Length - 1)
                                + reader.ReadLine();
                yield return line;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: didn't see the "splitted" comment.  you could add check if the last character in the line is a - then remove it and join the two lines together before you check for the word

Comment: Note: If you're using .NET 4.0 you can use File.ReadLines(filename) instead of having to write the AsLines method.

Comment: @ICR: Good point, I was writing and testing this in 2008 against .Net 3.5.

Answer (score 1):

What about if the line contains football?  Or fool? If you are going to go down the regular expression route you need to look for word boundaries.

```
Regex r = new Regex("\bfoo\b");
```

Also ensure you are taking into consideration case insensitivity if you need to.

Comment: this is a good point. to use my above sample you could add a space to the begining and end of each line then do a .Contains(" foo ")

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regular expressions in a case this simple. Simply loop over the lines and check if it contains `foo`.

```
using (StreamReader sr = File.Open("filename", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    string line = null;
    while (!sr.EndOfStream) {
        line = sr.ReadLine();
        if (line.Contains("foo"))
        {
            // foo was found in the file
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could construct a regex which allows for newlines to be placed between every character.

```
private static bool IsSubstring(string input, string substring)
{
    string[] letters = new string[substring.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < substring.Length; i += 1)
    {
        letters[i] = substring[i].ToString();
    }
    string regex = @"\b" + string.Join(@"(\r?\n?)", letters) + @"\b";
    return Regex.IsMatch(input, regex, RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
}
```